# SQL Server 2008 - how to get records that have a specific range of IDs

Tags: arrays, sql-server-2008, range

In SQL Server 2008 I would like to create a stored procedure to select specific products, passing their IDs as argument.

But I intend to bring as result a range of products.

This range must have the informed productIds argument value (for example: 1 and 8 and 29 - that means, the range MUST have productId 1 and productId 8 and productId 29).

The unwanted ranges (those like productId 1 and productId 8, or productId 1 and productId 29, or productId 8 and productId 29) won't be shown as result.

How can I filter those unwanted ranges from my query result?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ListProduct]
(
    @categoryId
    @productIds VARCHAR(4000) --Suppose we want to bring ONLY productIds 1 AND 8 AND 29 
)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 

    category_id,
    product_id, 
    product_name,
    FROM Product
    WHERE category_id = @category_id
    AND productId = --... is it better to use a function? a cursor?

END
```

If we have

```
CategoryId 1    
    ProductId 2    
    ProductId 8
    ProductId 20
    ProductId 29

CategoryId 2    
    ProductId 1    
    ProductId 3
    ProductId 20
    ProductId 29

CategoryId 3    
    ProductId 1    
    ProductId 8
    ProductId 20
    ProductId 29
```

The result would be

```
CategoryId 1 | ProductId 1
CategoryId 1 | ProductId 8
CategoryId 1 | ProductId 29
CategoryId 3 | ProductId 1
CategoryId 3 | ProductId 8
CategoryId 3 | ProductId 29
```

Here is what I've got so far:

```
CREATE TABLE #mylist(product_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT #mylist 
    SELECT Value FROM dbo.fn_split('1,8,29',',')

SELECT category_id,product_id
FROM    Product
WHERE   product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM #mylist)
```

But, when there's a product id missing like 8, this query is showing:

```
CategoryId 1 | ProductId 1
CategoryId 1 | ProductId 8 
CategoryId 1 | ProductId 29
CategoryId 2 | ProductId 1  --category2 should not be displayed,  
CategoryId 2 | ProductId 29 --  because product id 8 is missing....
CategoryId 3 | ProductId 1
CategoryId 3 | ProductId 8
CategoryId 3 | ProductId 29
```

Comment: it is pretty much never better to use a cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you're passing in a list of values to use a row level filter

*The* authoritative, ubiquitous, and oft-quoted article: ["Arrays and List in SQL Server"](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it done before by calling a function to convert the string of productids to a table. You can then join the table into your query to limit the results.

There seems to be an example of doing this here:
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=375

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a table variable as the parameter